# Karate : File not found error for js file which is in a reusable feature folder and this feature is called from another feature

Tags: karate

Karate: I have a reusable feature file which uses a js file.

- Folder1
    -test feature ( this is calling auth.feature)
- Utility folder

  - auth js file
  - auth feature
  - authRunner java

If I run `authRunner` as a Junit test it runs fine.
But if I call the auth feature file from another folder outside of Utility using read, I get an error that auth js file not found.

Answer (score 1):

Look for info on the `this:` prefix in the docs here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files hopefully that solves your issue.

```
* def foo = read('this:auth.js')
```